# Kentico import is not working after upgrade site into Kentico 11 from Kentico10

Tags: kentico

Our site has upgraded from Kentico 10 to K11 but due to some inconsistency upgrade was not proper finished. Site is running but I am getting error when I am Import object from another K11 instance. Error is

> 'dataType' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: dataType

screenshot:

[image: ImportError]

Answer (score 1):

If you're upgrade completed but had errors then the upgrade was not successful and it will haunt you until you go back find the issue, resolve it and do the upgrade properly until it succeeds.  Trying to import an older version of a site into a new version of a site is also not a proper way to upgrade either.  I know you stated your import was from another v11 instance but if you had another v11 instance why import it into a broken version 11 instance vs use the new one?

At any rate, the key is to get the "finished" messages in the event log and to ensure your upgrade is successful before continuing to import any other sites, modules, webparts, etc.

I suggest looking in the Kentico event log and see what the specifics are about the failure.  Also you might be able to post the XML from the export file which will help us be able to troubleshoot a bit more.

Comment: In event log, I am getting error of macro. i.e.Error while evaluating expression: if(NewReturning == "") {return "StatisticsCode = 'visitfirst' OR StatisticsCode = 'visitreturn'";} else { if (NewReturning.Contains("return")) { return "StatisticsCode = 'visitreturn'";} else {return "StatisticsCode = 'visitfirst'";}}|(user)3dn|(hash)57ffb69effa47559bc9b7372d228e131d545e8212db1c1c06fd035926eb43ac3

Comment: In event log, getting error Message: 'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType
Exception type: System.ArgumentNullException
Stack trace: 
at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType, String expr, MappingType type)
at CMS.Helpers.DataHelper.EnsureColumn(DataTable dt, String columnName, Type columnType) at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.GetEmptyDataSet(SiteImportSettings settings, String objectType, Boolean siteObjects, Boolean selectionOnly, GeneralizedInfo& infoObj, Boolean forceXMLStructure)

Comment: Explain more about your upgrade process.  What you did, what succeeded and what didn't.

Comment: We have a site which is in V11. This site has upgraded from K10 to K11 but code has proper upgraded and get succeed in build. When I am importing site object then getting error null reference on LoadDefaultSetting() method. As we know DB is inconsistent but not able to cause and also not able to get raise. May I request please suggest any DB table for Import/Export table which may be inconsistent from K11?

Comment: Regarding the DB upgrade, did this succeed or did it error out?  If it errored, the upgrade process is incomplete even if the code runs on the database.  I'd highly recommend going back to the database and running the upgrade again and focus on the issues on where it breaks/stops upgrading.