# Error while importing object in Kentico V11

Tags: c#, kentico

My website is currently running in Kentico version 11, when I am trying to Import object from another fresh instance of Kentico 11, i am getting:

> "'dataType' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: dataType".

Please review the link of screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ran.png

Can anyone provide the solution? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Asking the same question as a different user isn't what you should be doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625214/kentico-import-is-not-working-after-upgrade-site-into-kentico-11-from-kentico10/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kentico import is not working after upgrade site into Kentico 11 from Kentico10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625214/kentico-import-is-not-working-after-upgrade-site-into-kentico-11-from-kentico10)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but this could be a bug that was fixed in 11.05, what hotfix are you using?

"When attempting to import certain object types (for example pages) using the Kentico Import Toolkit utility, an error occurred in the source data preview step ("Cannot load default column mappings. Class not found.")."

Additionally, if this does not work, please post the full error from the event log!